# ckeditor plugins html5 video and audio not possible together?

Tags: ckeditor, html5-video, html5-audio, ckeditor4.x

I'm having a strange problem with adding plugins to CKEditor:

Step 1: 
I added the plugin html5audio. The config file:

```
... 
config.extraPlugins = 'html5audio';
config.toolbar = [ ['Html5audio'] ];
...
```

This works perfectly. No errors.

Step 2: 
Then I added the plugin html5video. The config file:

```
... 
config.extraPlugins = 'html5audio';
config.extraPlugins = 'html5video';
config.toolbar = [ ['Html5audio'],['Html5video'] ];
...
```

html5audio does not load and button disappears. Only video loads. Audio button in toolbar disappears. CKEditor shows no errors on browser console.log.

If I swap the sequence to:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'html5video';
config.extraPlugins = 'html5audio';
```

then audio loads and video disappears.

Seems that these plugins kick each other out, last one in queue wins.

I'm using CKeditor 4.7.3.

Thanks for any help and tips.

Answer (score 1):

You should use config.extraPlugins only once, otherwise you're overwriting the declaration. If you are going to add more than one extra plugin, the extraPlugins option expects a list of comma separated plugins. In your case it should be:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'html5video,html5audio';
```

CKEditor's documentation: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraPlugins